# Control wrapping spacing between div inline-blocks using CSS

Tags: css, html, whitespace

My page I'm working on is at http://www.derekbeck.com/1775/excerpts/

It looks all fine in desktop browsers, but on mobile screenshots, like below, it is forced to wrap. (see below the image for my questions...)

[image]
[(full sized image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ePP6.png)

I've tried to make it wrap gracefully, but I have two questions:

1) Is there some CSS way to control how the div inline-block (class="exnote2") `Want the entire chapter?<BR>Sign up for the newsletter!` wraps?

Specifically, I want:

1a) that `padding-left: 20px;` on the left side of it to be non-existent if it is on a second line as below (but it is necessary to keep it 20px from the PDF icon if it is indeed all on one line),

1b) some whitespace above the div inline-block (class="exnote2"), so that it is not so close to the "Read Online" icon. If I add padding-top or margin-top however, it effects the nice layout for the desktop version (linked above).

For what it's worth, for 1b) above, I did jury-rig a solution together for the entire inline block that follows the image, the entire div inline block that contains text (class="exitemdetails"). I did it this way:

```
.exitemdetails {
margin-left: 25px;
/* The following allows for graceful wrapping for mobile phones */
padding-top: 20px;
position: relative;
top: -10px; /* half the padding-top */
}
```

I could jury-rig something for the `Want the entire chapter?<BR>Sign up for the newsletter!` line too, but I suspect under different conditions it would not display as I hoped. Hence, I post here hoping for a better, more elegant solution, namely, how to use CSS to control the way div's wrap, and the spacing between them only if they do wrap.

2) I have one other question related to this: is there no simple CSS way to shrink that book cover image down when there is not space enough? I tried this, but it does nothing:

```
.eximage {
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
.eximage img {
max-width: 100%; 
height: auto;
}
```

Thanks for looking!
Derek

Comment: Have you considered using css media queries to change the layout of your page at different screen sizes? Might be worth a shot.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that... I can Google, but are there disadvantages or risks to this?

Comment: Not really, it's very common practice now.

Comment: Thanks, this worked awesome. I'd like to credit you with an answer. Can you post your note above as an answer instead of a comment? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using css media queries to change the layout of your page at different screen sizes? Might be worth a shot.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/